# Excel If/Then to replace text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am somewhat new to Excel, and I am not sure if I need a formula or a macro to accomplish this task.

I need to find all instances of "Jane Smith" and replace it with her employeeID, lets say its 513.

Names only appear in column A, and there may be more than one instance, so I need to search all cells under column A. I need to do this for multiple employees, so I'm guessing it a large `If/Then/Else`. Thanks!

Comment: If it's an one-time job, limited to Jane Smith, I'd use Replace (Ctrl-H). If it's not the case, could you describe, from where employeeID comes from.

Answer (score 1):

If the name is the only text in the cell then you could look into the `VLOOKUP` formula.

Answer (score 0):

Umm try this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim empVal As Range
    Dim employee As String: employee = "Jane Smith"
    Dim replaceStr As String: replaceStr = "513"
    Do While Not empVal Is Nothing
    Set empVal = activSheet.Columns(1).Find(What:=employee, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not empVal Is Nothing Then empVal = replaceStr
    Loop
End Sub
```

this tries to search every possible match of "Jane Smith" and replaces it with her employeeID

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to excel, you are not looking for a VBA solution as answered elsewhere.

The easiest way.....if you just want to replace "Jane Smith" to "513", what about this:
1.  Go to cell A1
2.  Ctrl +  Spacebar (to highlight column A)
3.  Ctrl + H (opens find/replace window)
4.  Put in "Jane Smith" in find and "513" in replace.

If you only have a few to do, this is the way to go.

If you want to use formulas to do this the right way, this is what you want:
1)  Create a new tab with 2 columns.  In column A, put all your employee names.  In column B, put the corresponding employee number.  If you have 10 employees, the table will run from A1 to B10.  Double click on the tab to name it "tab2"

2) In your current tab or file, go to cell A1 and insert a column (Alt + I + C).  Now you have a new blank column A and all the names are now in column B.  Let's say the first name starts on row 5, after all the heading stuff.  So your first name is in cell B5 hypothetically.

3)  In the new blank column A, in cell A5, use this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B5,'tab2'!$A$1:$B$10,2,0)
```

This formula will lookup in 'tab2' across cells A1-B10, to find what you linked in cell B5, which would be a name like "Jane Smith".  It will find this data in tab2, column A and look in the 2nd column.  The zero at the ends just tells the formula to use exact results only.

--If you wanted the numbers to stay in the new column B, there are many ways to do this, for instance, insert new column A, copy column B to column A, then write the vlookup formula in column B, looking off column A.  But this should get you started.